# Trouble with 'for' loop: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (52)

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am newer to python, and am trying to write a 'for' loop to perform a calculation on one column in a dataframe and put the results in another column. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (52)
```

What is the problem in my code?

```
#Import modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

#Read dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df.head(52)
```

Here is the data:

```
    Sample_ID   longitude   latitude    n_ppm   Mehlich_3_ppm   k_ppm   pH  Buffer_pH   OM  Zn_ppm
0   1   -100.922987 39.248554   32  20  29  7.1 7.2 2.7 3.4
1   2   -100.921920 39.248792   35  13  22  7.2 7.3 2.7 3.0
2   3   -100.920808 39.248584   34  8   21  7.5 7.3 2.6 1.2
3   4   -100.919779 39.248591   32  8   33  7.4 7.3 2.6 1.2
4   5   -100.918698 39.247933   42  7   26  7.1 7.1 2.6 1.2
5   6   -100.919457 39.247719   42  7   28  7.4 7.3 2.7 1.5
6   7   -100.920822 39.247916   36  9   32  7.4 7.3 2.8 1.6
7   8   -100.922241 39.247906   36  35  25  7.4 7.3 2.6 3.4
8   9   -100.923254 39.247781   31  35  26  7.5 7.3 3.0 4.2
9   10  -100.924217 39.247858   41  67  40  7.2 7.3 3.0 4.7
10  11  -100.925033 39.246966   50  46  26  7.6 7.3 2.9 2.3
11  12  -100.924190 39.246857   55  71  34  6.9 7.1 3.0 4.3
12  13  -100.923128 39.247089   50  68  27  7.2 7.2 2.7 3.6
13  14  -100.921795 39.246824   50  63  20  7.2 7.2 2.9 3.9
14  15  -100.920870 39.247048   50  43  32  7.2 7.2 3.1 3.1
15  16  -100.919414 39.246841   50  14  32  7.2 7.2 2.7 1.5
16  17  -100.918580 39.247120   50  10  23  7.3 7.3 2.6 1.2
17  18  -100.917600 39.246849   50  9   20  7.3 7.3 2.4 1.1
18  19  -100.917600 39.246111   50  23  36  7.3 7.3 3.3 1.4
19  20  -100.918410 39.245921   50  28  26  7.3 7.3 3.2 1.1
20  21  -100.919478 39.246194   50  99  23  7.1 7.1 3.4 3.0
21  22  -100.920773 39.245991   38  27  38  7.3 7.3 3.3 2.6
22  23  -100.921784 39.246063   37  26  40  7.4 7.3 3.4 3.5
23  24  -100.923103 39.246296   30  48  36  7.3 7.3 3.4 3.2
24  25  -100.924202 39.246112   34  64  33  7.1 7.2 3.2 3.1
25  26  -100.925255 39.246100   41  30  36  7.1 7.2 2.9 2.6
26  27  -100.925431 39.245284   33  29  34  7.7 7.4 3.0 2.3
27  28  -100.924429 39.245093   43  52  23  6.8 7.1 3.7 3.2
28  29  -100.923143 39.245226   36  24  36  7.1 7.2 2.9 3.8
29  30  -100.922008 39.245047   38  36  36  7.0 7.1 3.2 3.6
30  31  -100.920764 39.245258   39  17  35  7.2 7.2 3.3 3.5
31  32  -100.919717 39.244983   41  10  26  7.2 7.2 3.1 1.8
32  33  -100.918345 39.245352   37  13  27  7.2 7.3 3.3 1.7
33  34  -100.917390 39.245077   34  14  21  7.1 7.2 2.9 1.3
34  35  -100.917553 39.244407   41  67  22  7.1 7.2 3.6 1.9
35  36  -100.918440 39.244260   41  12  34  7.2 7.2 2.9 1.3
36  37  -100.919476 39.244483   32  9   23  7.4 7.3 2.8 1.2
37  38  -100.920955 39.244112   45  25  39  7.1 7.2 3.0 4.5
38  39  -100.921705 39.244254   36  27  39  7.2 7.2 3.2 3.8
39  40  -100.923370 39.244238   33  28  35  7.0 7.2 2.7 3.1
40  41  -100.924262 39.244383   45  32  32  7.1 7.2 3.0 3.0
41  42  -100.925087 39.244483   40  12  29  7.2 7.2 2.9 2.7
42  43  -100.924365 39.243440   30  59  23  6.9 7.1 3.8 3.2
43  44  -100.923045 39.243196   43  10  22  7.2 7.3 2.6 2.9
44  45  -100.921845 39.243471   37  23  20  7.1 7.2 3.1 3.3
45  46  -100.920755 39.243252   35  21  37  7.2 7.2 3.2 5.1
46  47  -100.919772 39.243325   45  12  36  7.1 7.2 2.6 2.1
47  48  -100.918568 39.243501   40  9   20  7.0 7.2 2.7 1.0
48  49  -100.919691 39.242702   34  8   32  7.2 7.2 3.0 2.2
49  50  -100.920656 39.242624   35  15  20  7.4 7.3 3.2 4.8
50  51  -100.922180 39.242513   36  9   28  7.0 7.2 2.8 2.4
51  52  -100.922826 39.242723   34  10  37  7.1 7.2 4.3 2.8
```

```
organicMatterField = df['OM']
yieldGoal = 150
nitrogenField = df['n_ppm']
pca = 0


nitrogen_needed = []
for nit in df['n_ppm']:
    nit = ((1.6 * int(yieldGoal)) - (organicMatterField * 20) - (nitrogenField) - float(pca))

#Create a new column within the dataframe        
df['Nitrogen recommendation (ppm)'] = nitrogen_needed

print(df)
```

The error is thrown here. It may be because my 'for' loop isn't written right, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You have two issues here: (1) `nit` is a reference to a point in `df['n_ppm']`, but you're assigning a value to it (the assigned value will not be saved) (2) `nitrogen_needed` is never updated.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Where the code says `nit = ...`, do you expect that to *change the contents of the Dataframe*? Because it definitely will not - Python variables do not work that way, and there is nothing that Pandas could do to change that.

Comment: "ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (52)" Did you try looking at the line of code that causes the error? Actually did you read the full error message and make sure you understand where the error occurs? (This is why you should [show complete error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146). I'm **guessing** that you see it on the line `df['Nitrogen recommendation (ppm)'] = nitrogen_needed`. Yes? So - did you try to *check what the value of `nitrogen_needed` is at this point*? Is it correct? No? Okay, then work backwards and figure it out.

Comment: (Hint: what is the value of `nitrogen_needed` initially? What part of the code is supposed to cause it to change after that?)

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592 and try to diagnose problems yourself before posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't understand why you do it with `for`-loop. It seems you could write it directly for full columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your calcuations but in `DataFrame` you can do it without `for`-loop

```
df['Nitrogen recommendation (ppm)'] = ((1.6 * 150) - (df['OM'] * 20) - (df['n_ppm']) - float(0))
```

---

And if you would need to use `for`-loop then you should iterate by rows, calculate value and `append()` to `nitrogen_needed`

```
nitrogen_needed = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result = ((1.6 * int(yieldGoal)) - (row['OM'] * 20) - (row['n_ppm']) - float(pca))
    nitrogen_needed.append(result)

df['Nitrogen recommendation (ppm)'] = nitrogen_needed
```

You don't append result to `nitrogen_needed` so you have empty list `[]` in `nitrogen_needed` - so finally you try to do

```
df['Nitrogen recommendation (ppm)'] = []
```

and this gives error because `df` has `52` rows, but empty list `[]` has `0` items/rows.

---

But if you need more complex calcuation (i.e. with `if/elif/else`) then you can use `apply(function)` instead of `for`-loop

```
yieldGoal = 150
pca = 0

def calculate(row):
    result = ((1.6 * int(yieldGoal)) - (row['OM'] * 20) - (row['n_ppm']) - float(pca))
    return result

df['Nitrogen recommendation (ppm)'] = df.apply(calculate, axis=1)
```

---

Full working example with data in code - so everyone can simply copy and test it.

I use `io.StringIO` to simulate file in memory but you should use `filename`

```
text = '''    Sample_ID   longitude   latitude    n_ppm   Mehlich_3_ppm   k_ppm   pH  Buffer_pH   OM  Zn_ppm
0   1   -100.922987 39.248554   32  20  29  7.1 7.2 2.7 3.4
1   2   -100.921920 39.248792   35  13  22  7.2 7.3 2.7 3.0
2   3   -100.920808 39.248584   34  8   21  7.5 7.3 2.6 1.2
3   4   -100.919779 39.248591   32  8   33  7.4 7.3 2.6 1.2
4   5   -100.918698 39.247933   42  7   26  7.1 7.1 2.6 1.2
5   6   -100.919457 39.247719   42  7   28  7.4 7.3 2.7 1.5
6   7   -100.920822 39.247916   36  9   32  7.4 7.3 2.8 1.6
7   8   -100.922241 39.247906   36  35  25  7.4 7.3 2.6 3.4
8   9   -100.923254 39.247781   31  35  26  7.5 7.3 3.0 4.2
9   10  -100.924217 39.247858   41  67  40  7.2 7.3 3.0 4.7
10  11  -100.925033 39.246966   50  46  26  7.6 7.3 2.9 2.3
11  12  -100.924190 39.246857   55  71  34  6.9 7.1 3.0 4.3
12  13  -100.923128 39.247089   50  68  27  7.2 7.2 2.7 3.6
13  14  -100.921795 39.246824   50  63  20  7.2 7.2 2.9 3.9
14  15  -100.920870 39.247048   50  43  32  7.2 7.2 3.1 3.1
15  16  -100.919414 39.246841   50  14  32  7.2 7.2 2.7 1.5
16  17  -100.918580 39.247120   50  10  23  7.3 7.3 2.6 1.2
17  18  -100.917600 39.246849   50  9   20  7.3 7.3 2.4 1.1
18  19  -100.917600 39.246111   50  23  36  7.3 7.3 3.3 1.4
19  20  -100.918410 39.245921   50  28  26  7.3 7.3 3.2 1.1
20  21  -100.919478 39.246194   50  99  23  7.1 7.1 3.4 3.0
21  22  -100.920773 39.245991   38  27  38  7.3 7.3 3.3 2.6
22  23  -100.921784 39.246063   37  26  40  7.4 7.3 3.4 3.5
23  24  -100.923103 39.246296   30  48  36  7.3 7.3 3.4 3.2
24  25  -100.924202 39.246112   34  64  33  7.1 7.2 3.2 3.1
25  26  -100.925255 39.246100   41  30  36  7.1 7.2 2.9 2.6
26  27  -100.925431 39.245284   33  29  34  7.7 7.4 3.0 2.3
27  28  -100.924429 39.245093   43  52  23  6.8 7.1 3.7 3.2
28  29  -100.923143 39.245226   36  24  36  7.1 7.2 2.9 3.8
29  30  -100.922008 39.245047   38  36  36  7.0 7.1 3.2 3.6
30  31  -100.920764 39.245258   39  17  35  7.2 7.2 3.3 3.5
31  32  -100.919717 39.244983   41  10  26  7.2 7.2 3.1 1.8
32  33  -100.918345 39.245352   37  13  27  7.2 7.3 3.3 1.7
33  34  -100.917390 39.245077   34  14  21  7.1 7.2 2.9 1.3
34  35  -100.917553 39.244407   41  67  22  7.1 7.2 3.6 1.9
35  36  -100.918440 39.244260   41  12  34  7.2 7.2 2.9 1.3
36  37  -100.919476 39.244483   32  9   23  7.4 7.3 2.8 1.2
37  38  -100.920955 39.244112   45  25  39  7.1 7.2 3.0 4.5
38  39  -100.921705 39.244254   36  27  39  7.2 7.2 3.2 3.8
39  40  -100.923370 39.244238   33  28  35  7.0 7.2 2.7 3.1
40  41  -100.924262 39.244383   45  32  32  7.1 7.2 3.0 3.0
41  42  -100.925087 39.244483   40  12  29  7.2 7.2 2.9 2.7
42  43  -100.924365 39.243440   30  59  23  6.9 7.1 3.8 3.2
43  44  -100.923045 39.243196   43  10  22  7.2 7.3 2.6 2.9
44  45  -100.921845 39.243471   37  23  20  7.1 7.2 3.1 3.3
45  46  -100.920755 39.243252   35  21  37  7.2 7.2 3.2 5.1
46  47  -100.919772 39.243325   45  12  36  7.1 7.2 2.6 2.1
47  48  -100.918568 39.243501   40  9   20  7.0 7.2 2.7 1.0
48  49  -100.919691 39.242702   34  8   32  7.2 7.2 3.0 2.2
49  50  -100.920656 39.242624   35  15  20  7.4 7.3 3.2 4.8
50  51  -100.922180 39.242513   36  9   28  7.0 7.2 2.8 2.4
51  52  -100.922826 39.242723   34  10  37  7.1 7.2 4.3 2.8
'''

import pandas as pd
import io

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+', index_col=0)

# --- version 1 ---

yieldGoal = 150
pca = 0

df['Nitrogen recommendation (ppm)'] = ((1.6 * yieldGoal) - (df['OM'] * 20) - (df['n_ppm']) - float(pca))

print(df)    
    
# --- version 2 ---

yieldGoal = 150
pca = 0

nitrogen_needed = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    result = ((1.6 * int(yieldGoal)) - (row['OM'] * 20) - (row['n_ppm']) - float(pca))
    nitrogen_needed.append(result)

df['Nitrogen recommendation (ppm)'] = nitrogen_needed    
    
print(df)
    
# --- version 3 ---

yieldGoal = 150
pca = 0

def calculate(row):
    result = ((1.6 * int(yieldGoal)) - (row['OM'] * 20) - (row['n_ppm']) - float(pca))
    return result

df['Nitrogen recommendation (ppm)'] = df.apply(calculate, axis=1)
  
print(df)
```